# Vagrant docker provisioner - cannot curl to localhost

Tags: docker, curl, vagrant, vagrantfile, kong

I am trying to emulate our microservice framework with Vagrant and Docker. I have a Vagrant VM which serves as an API gateway. In the `Vagrantfile` I used Docker provisioning to setup Kong. My objective is to bootstrap the necessary Kong services in the provisioning, using cURL.

My `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = 'apigateway'
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.110.110"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |docker|
    config.vm.provision "shell" do |sh|
      docker.pull_images "postgres:9.6"
      docker.pull_images "kong"
      docker.run "postgres:9.6",
        image: "postgres:9.6",
        args: "--name kong-db --network='host' -p 5432:5432 -e 'POSTGRES_USER=kong'  -e 'POSTGRES_DB=kong'  -e 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong'",
        auto_assign_name: false
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp"
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --reload"
      docker.run "kong-migrations",
        image: "kong",
        cmd: "kong migrations bootstrap",
        args: "--name kong-migrations --network='host' -e 'KONG_DATABASE=postgres' -e 'KONG_PG_HOST=localhost' -e 'KONG_PG_USER=kong' -e 'KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong'  -e 'KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong'",
        auto_assign_name: false,
        restart: "on-failure"
      docker.run "kong",
        image: "kong",
        args: "--name kong  --network='host' -p 8000:8000 -p 8443:8443 -p 8001:8001 -p 8444:8444 -e 'KONG_DATABASE=postgres' -e 'KONG_PG_HOST=localhost' -e 'KONG_PG_USER=kong' -e 'KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong' -e 'KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong' -e 'KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=127.0.0.1:8001, 127.0.0.1:8444 ssl'",
        auto_assign_name: false
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8000/tcp"
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8001/tcp"
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp"
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8444/tcp"
      sh.inline = "firewall-cmd --reload"
      ###### The cURL shell scripts that raised the errors #######
      sh.inline = "docker exec kong curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/services/ --data 'name=admin-api' --data 'url=http://localhost:8001'"
      sh.inline = "docker exec kong curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/services/admin-api/routes --data 'path=/admin-api'"
      sh.inline = "docker exec kong curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/services/admin-api/plugins --data 'name=jwt'"
      ####### --End of cURL scripts #####
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that the cURL scripts raised an error

```
default: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8001: Connection refused
```

However, the operation would be successful when I execute the cURL script inside the VM after `vagrant ssh`, i.e.

```
docker exec kong curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/services/ --data 'name=admin-api' --data 'url=http://localhost:8001'
```

I've tried using the VM IP `192.168.110.110` instead of `localhost` and I get `Connection reset by peer`.

What is wrong with this setup? What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working when you connect directly with ssh after the setup, then my guess is that your curl inside the vagrantfile is done too fast.
Maybe your server is not up yet when you do the curl.
What happens if you wait a little bit before the curl ? Does it work ?

Comment: i suspected that one too. i tried adding `sh.inline = "sleep 8"` but it did not work (maybe vagrant run shell scripts asynchronously?)